# How to stop page from refreshing when a POST request is sent using Django and AJAX

Tags: python, django, ajax, celery

I have a browse and upload file button. I also have a Start Task button. I want to browse and select a file. After doing so, I want to click Start Task which sends a POST request and NOT have the page reload. At the moment, when I click Start Task, the selected file gets cleared out. I am new to Django and Ajax so any help is appreciated.

Here is my index.html with my buttons:

```
<div class="container-fluid px-4">
    <h3 class="mt-4">Intrusion Detection System</h3>
    <form action="{% url 'upload' %}" class="row gy-1 gx-2 align-items-center" id='startIDS' method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        
        <div class='col-auto'>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file">
        </div>
        <div class='col-auto'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="float: right;" onclick="wait()" id="button2">Upload File</button>
            <script>
                function wait() {
                    //go_to_sleep.delay(5);
                    alert("Click Ok and then please wait for upload to finish");
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class='progress-wrapper'>
            <div id='progress-bar' class='progress-bar' style="background-color: #68a9ef; width: 0%;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div id="progress-bar-message">Waiting for progress to start...</div>
        <div id="celery-result"></div>
        <script src="{% static 'celery_progress/celery_progress.js' %}"></script> <!--CELERY-->
    </form>

    <form method="post" id="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button id="ajax-button" type="submit">Start task</button>
    </form>

    {% if task_id %}                    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#ajax-button").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // STOP PAGE FROM REFRESHING 
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{% url "upload" %}',
                    data: {
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                        var progressUrl = "{% url 'celery_progress:task_status' task_id %}";
                        CeleryProgressBar.initProgressBar(progressUrl);
                        });
                        $('#button2').click();
                       // $("#ajax-button").text(response.seconds)
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        console.log(response)
                        $('#button2').click();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    {% endif %}
```

Views.py:

```
# Render IDS view
def startIDS(request):
    if request.session.__contains__('MAL'):
        MAL_Data = request.session['MAL']
    else:
        MAL_Data = None

    context = {
        "MAL_Data":MAL_Data
    }

    # Variable used to result results to form to be displayed.
    context = {
        "MAL_Data":MAL_Data
    }

    # Return the rendered webpage.
    # CELERY
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        task = go_to_sleep.delay(5)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'task_id': task.task_id})
    
    # ORIGINAL
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

I have tried changing the AJAX function to just display a simple div tag. This does work. I am just not sure why my code above does not prevent the page from refreshing. Is this even possible?

INDEX.HTML:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#post-button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "myapp:myview" %}',
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#response').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

VIEWS.PY

```
 Render IDS view
def startIDS(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
        # Handle the POST request here
        response_data = {'message': 'This is the response message!'}
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
    else:
        # Handle GET requests here
        return render(request, 'mytemplate.html')
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` will normally do the trick. It is missing in your second code snippet.